# File type management in java with an JPA binding

Tags: java, jsf, jpa-2.0

I have a File linked to an object as a byte[]. This file is stored in DB in a `Blob column type` and the binding is made by the `@Lob` annotation.

The problem is that this system doesn't manage the file type (ie : I upload a pdf but when a download it, it doesn't have any type)

Can you give me an easy way to deal with this type of issue ?

My first thought was to store the type in a simple `varchar column` but how I will change the type of the stream on the byte[] getter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imho you'r right about using separate field for mimeType for lob content. So you can during upload deduce mimetype a store it into your jpa entity.

in your download servlet, you can write something like :

```
String mimetype = entity.getMimeType();

// sets response content type
if (mimetype == null) {
    mimetype = "application/octet-stream";
}
response.setContentType(mimetype);
response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
String fileName = (new File(filePath)).getName();

// sets HTTP header
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you successfully persist the file in the database. In order to download it and to know the type, you have to provide the `content-type` within the `HttpSessionResponse` object.

In `JSF`, you can do it like this:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
response.reset();
response.setContentType(contentType);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

After that, you have to pass the stream to the response's `OutputStream`.

If you're uploading different types of files, it's a good idea to store somewhere in the database the exact type of the uploaded documents. Then, for each of the document types you have, you can find the corresponding `content-type` (also referred as `MIME-type` or `internet-media-type`).

[Here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list)'s a list of all the `MIME-types`.